# Is precision in recommender system related to mean average error (MAE)?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, precision-recall, information-retrieval

A recommender system is being evaluated while increasing the neighborhood size. The highest precision was achieved between 10-15 neighbors(users) while the lowest MAE was in the range from 30-40 users. Shouldn't the highest precision be achieved when the MAE is the lowest? If not, how the above results can be explained?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more the problem? The context? What algorithm is use, etc...

Comment: Collaborative filtering algorithm, using NearestNUserNeighborhood with different n , https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/neighborhood/NearestNUserNeighborhood.html